# Is this proof of Cauchy's mean value correct?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to come up with my own proof of Cauchy's mean value theorem.
My proof of Cauchy's mean value theorem:
Assume for contradiction it is false.
Then $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}-\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{g(a)-g(b)}$ must be positive or negative for the interval $[a,b]$, by the contrapositive of the intermediate value theorem.
WLOG it is positive. So we get an increasing function returns at the same point twice. Contradiction.
I feel like the rapport between the last two steps are weak. Can you help me fix it? I didn't find a similar proof online.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous.

Comment: Does differentiable necessarily mean $f'$ is continuous?

Comment: You state "Contradiction." Can you *explicitly* point out the contradiction?

Comment: I edited my proof. That is a good observation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Assume that $g(a)\neq g(b)$ and define $h(x)=f(x)-Cg(x)$, for some constant $C\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $h(a)=h(b)$. From this, we have

$$h(a)=h(b)\Longleftrightarrow f(a)-Cg(a)=f(b)-Cg(b)\Longleftrightarrow C=\frac{f(b)-f(b)}{g(b)-g(a)}$$

Since $h:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and satisfies $h(a)=h(b)$, by Rolle's theorem exist $c\in(a,b)$ such that $h'(c)=0$, i.e., $\dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$.